# Watch command with ls and shell globs

Tags: bash, wildcards, watch

I tried running the command

```
watch -n1 ls foo/bar*
```

which I want to list files matching `foo/bar*` every second. However, what actually happens is that the shell expands the glob and what `watch` runs is, say,

```
ls foo/bar1.txt foo/bar2.txt
```

Thus, if another file `foo/bar3.txt` is added later it won't show up in the output. Is there a neat way to do this without creating a script file containing

```
ls foo/bar*
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Wrap it in strong quotes so that the wildcard isn't parsed immediately:

```
$ watch -n1 'ls foo/bar*'
```

Comment: And what is the difference between single and double quotes in this case?

Comment: Single quotes in bash don't perform shell expansion (wildcards and variables remain in their original form), double quotes in bash performs wildcard expansion. You can use this fact in many places.

Comment: elegant. Faced same issue - didn't expect answer was simple one.